# Comparing features in a asp.net web application using different database technologies

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, linq, comparison, db4o

I have a webstore which sells components (it is a academic project) which looks like [this](http://postimage.org/image/1sro3svz8/). I have developed the same web application using following database technologies:

1. MS Sql Server with Stored procedures and sql data reader
2. LINQ to Sql
3. DB4o using LINQ (Client/Server)

What features can I compare apart from the technical and theoretical details between relational database and object oriented database ?

It is my graduate/master's thesis final project. I want the features that i want to compare to be more practical and interesting so that I can draw some concrete and meaningful conclusions rather than abstract comparisons which don't create much interest and hard for inference.

Please help me.

Feel free to express your opinions.

Thanks in anticipation

***PS: Don't downvote or flag this post, if some one doesn't like this question u may delete it after getting answered***

Comment: I specifically told in my post script that if some one doesn't like this question they can delete this question why still downvote ???

Comment: Answer it then delete it? SO doesn't work like that. If you don't want to be down-voted, my advice would be to edit the question yourself by removing the last 5 paragraphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a site that compare DALs, maybe you can get some ideas for what other think you can compare.

http://ormbattle.net/

Also here is my first question on StackOverflow that I compare 4 dals for speed and optimization. 
[Benchmark Linq2SQL, Subsonic2, Subsonic3 - Any other ideas to make them faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363735/benchmark-linq2sql-subsonic2-subsonic3-any-other-ideas-to-make-them-faster)

> What features can I compare apart

In you case I was try to compare the speed, and if the conversion to a DAL can give the same or more features that can get with out it. For example, can you get all the same questions that you can do direct with SQL or not, and what is the limitations.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating some **performance** benchmarks and do a side-by-side compare of the three different DB technologies (these are not methodologies) for given types of queries.

Comment: No prob, but I still think you should remove the last 5 paragraphs because they are causing you to get down votes IMHO :-)