# How to use SubSonic 3.0.4 with ASP.NET Web Forms Website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, subsonic, subsonic3

How to use `SubSonic 3.0.4` with ASP.NET Web Forms Website?

I am using Visual Web Developer Express Edition 2008 and i want to generate a `Data Access Layer` using `SubSonic 3.0.4` for `ASP.NET Website`. Is that possible??

If not then , will it be wise to use `SubSonic 2` ? What are the downsides??

Comment: It will be wise to use subsonic 2 because is a lot faster: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363735/benchmark-linq2sql-subsonic2-subsonic3-any-other-ideas-to-make-them-faster

Comment: @Aristos Any way i can use subsonic 3 with web forms??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subsonic 3 requires the t4 templates which are only supported in the full version of VS - not web developer.

Yes, you can use either version with web forms. I've been having problems with medium trust on some shared server providers and SS3, I'm looking into that at the moment.

The actual official SubSonic site is at : [subsonic.wekeroad.com](http://subsonic.wekeroad.com). 
Subsonicproject.com is a secondary site no longer maintained and largely broken.

Answer (score 0):

I cant quite remember whether subsonic works as an extension - if so the you'll need the pro version of visual studio. However you will be able to use Microsoft's ORM Entity Framework out of the box with Web Developer - check out the code first option its really quite pleasant to work with and can be easier to learn than some of the more mature ORM's like NHibernate and LLBLGen.

Entity Framework resources http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907

As an aside I would recommend upgrading to Visual Studio 2012 - it has loads more useful features than 2008 and you can still use it to target framework versions down to 2.0!

Comment: Seems you can integrate subsonic this guide should show you how http://shawnoster.com/blog/post/Getting-SubSonic-Setup-in-Visual-Studio.aspx and here http://blog.benhall.me.uk/2007/10/setting-up-subsonic.html

Comment: Any way i can use subsonic 3 with web forms??